# limits of multivariable functions

Tags: calculus

With a view to proving that the limits of some multivariable functions don't exist on certain points, I'm trying to prove the following:

Suppose $f$ is a function from a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $x \in X'$. If ∃  $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=b$,then ∀ $Y \subset  X$ so that $a \in Y'$, ∃ $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f|_{Y}(x) = b$.

So, I tried using this definition of limit: $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=b$ if ∀ $ε>0$,∃ $δ>0$ so that $f(B(a,\delta) \cap X) \subset B(b,\epsilon)$.
Since $Y \subset  X$ we have $f(B(a,\delta) \cap Y) \subset B(b,\epsilon)$.
But i don't really know what to do next.
I also tried starting from the assumption that ∃ $Y$ so that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f|_{Y}(x) \neq b$ and proving that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)$ is not $b$, but i couldn't get anywhere with that either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just changed your math to LaTeX for the most part, if something looks wrong let me know. I'm particularly concerned with the restriction notation. Usually I write $f|_U$ to denote $f$ restricted to $U \subseteq dom(f)$. Should I make that change as well?

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying (unsuccessfully) to get the hang of LaTeX. It would be great if you could make that change as well. Thanks again.

Comment: I may just be dense, but I can't quite see what you're trying to do here. You want to show the function and its restriction share the same limit in as much as they can be compared? This is usually true, we just need that the restriction does not somehow spoil the limit point. If the restricted domain has an open neighborhood around the limit point then the limits will agree. The limit is a local object. On the other hand, if a there was some funny business on one-side and you cut it off with the restriction then we could have the situation that the restricted limit exists even though..

Comment: the unrestricted limit d.n.e. For example, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ d.n.e. for $f(x) = \sin( 1/x)$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \leq 0$. Ok, so restrict to $(-\infty,0]$ then the limit at zero exists. I'll check back in the morning, but perhaps someone else will help...